# How to create an answer in a table with jagged arrays?

Tags: arrays, html-table

I created a table and I would like to calculate the average temperature of each row. I managed to create the table and all the data inside but I'm really stuck on the final part. How would you calculate the average temperature of each row and display it in the table?

```
<body onload="imprime();">


    <div id="container"></div>

    <script>

    var temperature = [ 
 ["","00-08","08-16","16-24"], 
 ["Malmö",12,16,9], 
 ["Mariestad",13,15,10], 
 ["Stockholm",13,15,13], 
 ["Upphärad",14,16,15], 
 ["Göteborg",13,14,12] 
 ];

    function imprime() {
        varMyinnerHTML = "<table border ='1'>";

        for (i=0;i<temperature.length;i++)
            {
            varMyinnerHTML +="<tr>";
            for (j=0;j<temperature[i].length;j++)

                {
            varMyinnerHTML +="<td>" + temperature[i][j]+"</td>";
                }
            varMyinnerHTML +="</tr>";
                }
            varMyinnerHTML +="</table>";

    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=varMyinnerHTML;
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change for loop like this. took a variable & add all values in it then just simple average. See your answer in console.

```
   for (i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
      varMyinnerHTML += "<tr>";
      let k = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < temperature[i].length; j++) {
          varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + temperature[i][j] + "</td>";
          if (i > 0 && j > 0)
              k += temperature[i][j];
      }
      if (i != 0){
         varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + (k/3) + "</td>";
      }
      varMyinnerHTML += "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: But what if I need to have the answer in the table (which is the case) ?

Comment: Check with my latest answer.